# NSNotification.Name.didBecomeActiveNotification not found

Tags: swift, macos, nsnotifications, notificationcenter

I'm working on a macOS app on Xcode 10.1 with a 10.14 deployment target. According to the documentation there should be a NSNotification.Name.didBecomeActiveNotification, but the build fails with a `Type 'NSNotification.Name?' has no member 'didBecomeActiveNotification'` error. I have imported Cocoa, AppKit and Foundation. Here is the relevant code:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
    print("\(notification)")
}
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's now a class property of `NSApplication`

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
```

Comment: Complete and perfect!